# Relationship between points for a multi-dimensional strictly concave function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a strictly concave, twice continuously differentiable function defined on $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. Let $(x^*,y^*)$ be its unique maximum. Suppose some point $(x_1,y_1)$ in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is such that both partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x_1,y_1)$ are strictly positive. Is it then always true that $x_1<x^*$ AND $y_1<y^*$?

Comment: What is $R^{++}$?

Answer (score 0):

No.
Let $$f(x,y)=-(2x^{2}+2y^{2}+3xy).$$ Let $p=(0,0)$ and $q=(-1,0.5)$. Then $p$ is it's maximum, $$\nabla f(x,y)=-(4x+3y,4y+3x),$$ so $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(q)=2.5\text{ and }\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(q)=1.$$
To understand the example it's worth taking a look on the picture.
[image]

Comment: Great counterexample. Thank you.